# (error) ERR unknown command 'XTRIM' on redis-cli

Tags: redis, redis-cli, redisclient

I am getting ERROR: `"(error) ERR unknown command 'XTRIM'"` while running on redis-cli.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> info
# Server
redis_version:3.2.12
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:7897e7d0e13773f
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
gcc_version:4.8.5
process_id:36305
run_id:5759acadb741325a8022dad3c136dd9cc26d66d8
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:2062
uptime_in_days:0
hz:10
lru_clock:9078505
executable:/usr/bin/redis-server
config_file:/etc/redis.conf
```

Above is the info of the redis server.

**No Command starting "X" 'XTRIM','XADD','XGROUP' is not working.**

```
[root@localhost lib]# redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> XTRIM TXNLOG MAXLEN 0
(error) ERR unknown command 'XTRIM'
127.0.0.1:6379> XGROUP CREATE TXNLOG test 0 MKSTREAM
(error) ERR unknown command 'XGROUP'
```

Comment: You are trying to use Redis Stream commands, and Redis Stream is supported by Redis 5.0. However, your Redis version is 3.2.12.

Comment: @for_stack thanks a lot ... it works...!!!!:)

Answer (score 4):

You should upgrade to redis 5.x

To do this first go to `/tmp` directory:

```
$ cd /tmp
```

Then download and `make` redis by source:

```
$ wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-5.0.5.tar.gz
$ tar xzf redis-5.0.5.tar.gz
$ cd redis-5.0.5
$ make
```

And then run redis-server:

```
$ src/redis-server
```